# My app keeps force closing when using 2 intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Why do my android apps keep closing when using 2 intent? when I delete one of them, it's work. especially if I delete the "Reg" Button in the java files.
Thanks

XML Files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginAct">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daftar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/daftar"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Linktext"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/lewat"
        android:textColor="@color/textwhite" />
```

Java Files (If I deleted the "Reg" Button from this file, the app is working, but otherwise it will force close after the splash screen):

```
    package com.soerja.ngalamhistory;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class LoginAct extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_login);

    Button Pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    Button Reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.daftar);

    Pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginAct.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginAct.this, RegisAct.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
    }
```

AndroidManifest Files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.soerja.ngalamhistory">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashAct"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginAct"
        android:label="@string/applogin"
        android:theme="@style/LogTheme"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisAct"
        android:label="@string/appdaftar"
        android:theme="@style/LogTheme"></activity>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

I would really appreciate your help because this is my school project :)

Comment: Where is your reg button in your xml ? You're trying to cast a textview to button.

Comment: your code is not complete please add your complete code

Comment: Its the "daftar" id.

Comment: I cut a few to be post in here.

Comment: add your logocat crash codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting a TextView into a Button. Probably the problem is a invalid cast exception.

In XML, you define the "daftar" as a TextView, but in java you are trying to use it as a Button.

Change it

```
Button Reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.daftar);
```

To it

```
TextView Reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daftar);
```

Or change your XML implamentation, defining "daftar" as a Button

Answer (score 0):

here you are using your text view id

```
 android:id="@+id/daftar"
```

as a reference to declaring button

```
Button Reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.daftar);
```

so i think ,that may be the reason for crash

try this method :

add this in your text xml code:

```
android:onClick="daftar"
```

add for java class use this:

```
public void daftar(View v)
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisAct.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}
```

and remove the old java code you used for this text view:

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort mate :D